# Is it possible to horizontally align individual characters with letter-spacing in CSS?

Tags: css

Given a CSS rule of `letter-spacing: 16px;`, I notice that the characters are left-aligned within their "box", and make the cursor jump ahead to the far right, as if I added an extra space *after* the character.

Is it possible to use `letter-spacing`, but having the characters horizontally aligned within their new extended boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. The reason is, this will act as a `padding` / `margin` but not like a `position`. But yeah, if you want something like that, you can use `inline-flex` and use `order` to reorder.

```css
p {display: inline-flex;}
p span {padding: 3px;}
p span.second {order: 1;}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="first">first</span>
  <span class="second">second</span>
  <span class="third">third</span>
</p>
```

This is just a POC. Please feel free to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is for an INPUT element, however, for a PIN user input. I noticed this weirdness and my OCD kicked in. (I ask myself silly trivial questions a lot.) If it had been within another HTML element, I would have used JavaScript to wrap individual characters within styled SPAN elements. :/

Comment: Ah nice. Understood. I guess you can do only using JavaScript then. Not possible using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As have been said, [`letter-spacing`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#tracking) does not have a mean to position the character in the unit, more precisely really just adds "tracking".

From your comment it is apparent what you want to get, and it is kinda achievable, provided you can split your input to multiple one-character ones:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

input {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px; /* mimics letter-spacing*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="pin1[]" maxlength=1 oninput="this.nextElementSibling.select()" value="m">
  <input name="pin1[]" maxlength=1 oninput="this.nextElementSibling.select()" value="i">
  <input name="pin1[]" maxlength=1 value="m">
</div>

<div>
  <input name="pin2[]" maxlength=1 oninput="this.nextElementSibling.select()" value="i">
  <input name="pin2[]" maxlength=1 oninput="this.nextElementSibling.select()" value="m">
  <input name="pin2[]" maxlength=1 value="i">
</div>
```

Comment: It sure isn't pretty, but I get the idea and I guess using JavaScript to dynamically create INPUT elements, and implement proper navigation, is most likely the only solution, here.Too bad that there isn't a `letter-align` property.